# Add file to desktop when users login on a machine

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I have setup a test lab for some pieces of software that is slowly expanding and having new machines decommissioned and added to the environment. I am trying to write a GPO in the test domain to place a file on the desktop with some information and stuff to help them get started.

This is what the configuration looks like, but it doesn't appear to be working after forcing a GP update.  I was using this as a reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/02dc525d-fe7a-497a-b6ec-a2bff4df98ac/how-to-place-files-on-users-desktop-with-gpp?forum=winserverGP

What am I missing here?  All servers are on Server 2012 R2 I've tried various paths, such as c:\user\%userprofile%\Desktop, %Desktop%, I just can't seem to get it to propagate to the desktop. I added an environmental variable named DesktopDir that should point to %USERPROFILE%\Desktop but when I look on the machine it is labeled was c:\user\machinename$\desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out - the file path it didn't like because I was using a c$ share.  I created a fully qualified share path and it worked.